# Database generation in powerdesigner

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, powerdesigner

I designed a PhysicalDataModel (PDM) in SAP powerdesigner that contain 280 tables with indexes,primary keys, foreign keys and sequences. 
I've checked model for many times and no errors returned. I generate database from PDM and in generated file i have 2 errors on one column and 7 table doesn't generate completely. Indexes,sequences and relations for this 7 tables are created but the CREATE TABLE statement for these tables are not generated.
How can i solve this problem??

same error for all 7 tables :

2 error(s), 0 warning(s)

(1) (Column "EXEC_PERCENT_DRAFT"):
   [translation error] unresolved member: DefaultOnNull

(1) (Column "EXEC_PERCENT_DRAFT"):
   [translation error] unresolved member: DefaultOnNull;

for example, table KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR : (CREATE TABLE does not exist)

Search "KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR" (11 hits in 1 file)
  new 1 (11 hits)

```
Line 2493: /* Table: KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR*/

Line 3457: REFERENCES KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (ACTIVITY_ID, UNIT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, WORK_PERIOD_ID, PLAN_ID, STEP_ID)

Line 3765: CREATE INDEX KBDG_ACTEXEC_BDGTDT_IDX ON KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (

Line 3785: CREATE INDEX KBDG_ACTEXEC_CTRLDT_IDX ON KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (

Line 3805: CREATE INDEX KBDG_ACTEXEC_PLNGDT_IDX ON KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (

Line 3825: CREATE INDEX KBDG_ACTEXEC_SPNDDT_IDX ON KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (

Line 4140: REFERENCES KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (ACTIVITY_ID, UNIT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, WORK_PERIOD_ID, PLAN_ID, STEP_ID)

Line 4207: REFERENCES KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (ACTIVITY_ID, UNIT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, WORK_PERIOD_ID, PLAN_ID, STEP_ID)

Line 4737: REFERENCES KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (ACTIVITY_ID, UNIT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, WORK_PERIOD_ID, PLAN_ID, STEP_ID)

Line 7388: REFERENCES KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (ACTIVITY_ID, UNIT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, WORK_PERIOD_ID, PLAN_ID, STEP_ID)

Line 14890: REFERENCES KBDG_ACTIVITY_EXECUTOR (ACTIVITY_ID, UNIT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, WORK_PERIOD_ID, PLAN_ID, STEP_ID)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show the [code you have so far](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help.

Comment: i have no code for create table, this is my problem

Comment: Power Designer generates SQL.But those aren't Oracle errors. They look like they are related to some custom extension: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38628.1652/doc/html/rad1232022603629.html

Comment: Which version of PowerDesigner are you using?

Comment: powerdesigner16.6

Comment: I know those aren't oracle errors and also i read the sybase help center.

Comment: How is this column defined? Is it a standard column, or a Java class?

Comment: all columns are standard column. defined in oracle sql worksheets.

Comment: Can you share the definition of this column: data type, default, pk, mandatory, fk... ?

Comment: name = exec_percent_draft, data type=number, default value=0

Comment: not primary key, not foreign key and not mandatory